# Certificate pinning in Android - no peer certificate

Tags: android, ssl

I am trying to use Moxie Marlinspike's sample [project](https://github.com/moxie0/AndroidPinning) to pin CA certificate in my Android app.

I had to make changes like changing gradle version, target sdk version. In his build.gradle I had an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25223326/682869). I commented out the `uploadAcrhives` block to resolve it.

I used it as follows in the app :

```
public class CAPinning {

    public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient(Context context) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

        try {

            // I created my own CA using open SSL - I converted the ca.crt file to .pem
            // using cat ca.crt > ca.pem, and then used the python script provided by
            // the author to generate the hash, which is used as a pin here

            String[] pins = new String[]{"14cafa386cb573635ec05c3d93f9117968ac5d71"};
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new PinningSSLSocketFactory(context, pins, 0), 443));

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, schemeRegistry);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, httpParams); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("EXP", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

I used the httpClient to send a request to my server :

```
 HttpClient httpClient = CAPinning.getHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
 httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.example.com"));
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
W/System.err﹕ at org.thoughtcrime.ssl.pinning.PinningSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(PinningSSLSocketFactory.java:147)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.sslsampleapp.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:173)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.sslsampleapp.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:131)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Can any one suggest a way to resolve it?

I'm sure I am using the right pem file and the site's certificate is signed with that CA.

```
Certificate chain
  0 s:/C=US/ST=**/L=****/O=***/OU=***/CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=*****
    i:/C=US/ST=**/L=****/O=myCA/OU=myCA/CN=myCA/emailAddress=*****
```

Comment: *"No peer certificate"* - sounds like the server is not presenting a certificate. Are you using anonymous cipher suites? Where did you get Certificate Chain from? Was it `s_client` or another utility?

Comment: I tested visiting the domain name using the Android's browser and the server is presenting the certificate as expected.

Comment: Related to your question (and you're not the only person who does this): why do you set up a website on the public internet for millions of people to bang on; and yet hide it from the 3 or 4 people on Stack Overflow who could actually help you with the problem?

Comment: I am testing in an internal environment, the domain name can't reached from outside at the moment.

Comment: I have removed all reference to mywebsite.com .. thank you for pointing out my mistake on SO.

Comment: Use `example.com`. That's why IANA reserves it.

Comment: Ok sure .. will do that.